# Is this right punctuation (comma) in the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

> We generally construct these sentences using the word wish, followed by the verb of the desired action.

Does this need a comma? If so, is it in the right place?

Comment: It is right , atleast not wrong !

Comment: Ok. Thank you .

Comment: When you say it, you should be able to hear the tone dip after _wish_ and rise on _followed_. That's what they sound like in the reader's mental ear.

Comment: If you dropped the comma, readers might pause to ask themselves what a "word wish" was…

It's debatable whether the word "wish" would be better quotated, and that's a different point.